# The Chrome extension. Assign buttons with functions in Popup menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Please help! How assign buttons with functions in Popup menu?

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Common Messages for Intercom</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href='#'>Message 1</a>
<br>
<a href='#'>Message 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function Button1() {
  // Something
}

function Button2() {
  // Something
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Provide more insight on what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Try the code: `<a href='#' onclick='Button1'>Message 1</a>` `<a href="#" onclick='Button2'>Message 2</a>`

Comment: @gui47 Harmful advice [because reasons](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

Comment: By the way, this is best practice to put the scripts at the end of the body.

Comment: @Xan Thanks! I forgot the Content Security Policy.

Comment: @Elad Is it? Chrome documentation suggests using `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: So? Twice are best parctices. Place the script at the buttom, improve the loading speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to be able to identify your elements. Therefore, give them unique IDs:

   ```
   <a href='#' id="btn1">Message 1</a>
   <br>
   <a href='#' id="btn2">Message 2</a>
   ```
2. You need to bind your functions to the `click` event:

   ```
   function Button1() {
     // Something
   }

   document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", Button1);
   ```
3. The above will not work yet, as it will execute before DOM is built (and therefore `#btn1` does not exist yet). Wrap things in `DOMContentLoaded` listener to make sure DOM is ready:

   ```
   function Button1() {
     // Something
   }

   function Button2() {
     // Something
   }       

   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", Button1);
     document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", Button2);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

### popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Common Messages for Intercom</title>

</head>
<body>
<a id="button1" href='#'>Message 1</a>
<br>
<a id="button2" href='#'>Message 2</a>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### popup.js

```
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = Button1;
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = Button2;

function Button1() {
  // Something
}

function Button2() {
  // Something
}
```

Comment: Nice theory. In fact, if you put the script at end of the body this will work.

Comment: **If**. Your answer as is was at first would not work.